# Did I differentiate correctly?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Good evening

I have one question. Are the results of my differentiation correct? I saw maths and derivatives at university but that was long time ago. :) I forgot.

Thanks for help.

> \begin{align*}
> z(\theta_1,\theta_2)&=\theta_1-\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2-360^\circ}{2}\\
> \frac{\partial z}{\partial\theta_1} &= \frac{1}{2}\\
> \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta_2}& = -\frac{1}{2}
> \end{align*}
>   [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byzLX.png)

Comment: The verb for the act of taking a derivative is _differenation_, not derivation. It's a thing I pick at with my students. But nonetheless you've done it correctly.

Comment: Seems right to me !

Comment: Yes you did it right.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It is simpler to see that those are correct if you first write $z(\theta_1, \theta_2)= \frac{\theta_1}{2}- \frac{\theta_2}{2}- 180$.

Comment: @Sean: actually, differentiation (the task/process of finding the derivative of...) is a noun (and differentiate is the corresponding verb), while the result of such effort is the derivative.

Comment: Whoa, a simple mistake! Still though, I do pick at that.

Comment: @Sean I do to! ;-)

Comment: @Sean  I also took liberty to edit the question accordingly, at the prompting of your grammatical flags!